# Monolith, onion architecture, multiple database types, How to do "transaction" from 2 different service classes with different database types?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, repository, unit-of-work

I want to ask about architecture

I use onion architecture.
i have 2 big modules, User Module & Order Module

The User Module uses mysql
The Order module uses mongodb

Both have service class.

When a user places an order, the Service class in the order module will call the service from the User module to update the User data.

How to do "transaction" from 2 different service classes with different database types?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this you need a transaction engine that sits outside your databases. While they have existed in the past, and maybe some still do, you are better off not doing this. If you absolutely need these things to be transactional, put them in the same server. If not, program your application to work in an eventually consistent model and use things like message queues for de-coupling your services.

Multi-phase transactions like this always get complicated and are usually not worth the hassle.